# Chance on throwing last number of full house with two die

Tags: probability

I had a discussion with my family again while playing Yahtzee. Lets say I have 3 throws per round with 5 die. The first round I throw

```
3 - 3 - 2 - 2 -5
```

I need full house so I need

```
3 - 3 - 3 - 2 -2
```

or

```
2 - 2 - 2 -3 -3
```

After the first throw I need a 3rd 3 or a 3rd 2. So we had a discussion about the chance to throw the last needed number.

So they asked me what is the chance? But I really don't know how I should calculate it while the problem looks fairly simple to me. Hopefully someone can help and can explain it in a way 'everyone'  can understand the way to calculate it.

Comment: Your brother in law should revisit the addition of fractions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The chances to have neither a 2 or a 3 is
$$
\left( \frac 4 6 \right)^2,
$$
so the result is
$$
1 - \left( \frac 4 6 \right)^2 = \frac 5 9 \approx 55.6\%
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the event "getting a 2 or 3 on first roll".

Let $B$ be the event "getting a 2 or 3 on second roll".

We want to find $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$.

But since you stop rolling if event $A$ occurs, you will never have $A \cap B$, so $P(A \cap B) = 0$, so $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$.

While $P(A) = \frac{2}{6}$, your father made the mistake of thinking $P(B) = \frac{2}{6}$, as well. This is not true because you stop rolling if you observe $A$, so there's a lesser chance of observing $B$. However, $P(B | A^c) = \frac{2}{6}$. $P(B) = P(B | A^c) P(A^c) = \frac{2}{6} ( 1 - \frac{2}{6})$, so

$P(A \cup B) = \frac{2}{6} + \frac{2}{6} ( 1 - \frac{2}{6}) = 1- (\frac{4}{6})^2$,

which agrees with Stefan's answer.

Side note: The reason your brother's solution fails is because $\frac{2}{6} + \frac{2}{6} \ne \frac{4}{12}$.